# Is there any way to call a component method on clicking a "non react" dom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables

Here's the scenario. I have created tables using **jQuery Datable plug-in**. In the last column, there's a **button** (an *non react* HTML element) for all rows. Since all HTML for table is automatically created by the plug-in, we can't use JSX component for the button and hence can't use **onClick** react listener.

Here's what I'm doing currently:

In my regular script file (non react):

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-button", function(){
   //show a popup and add content in it using ajax
});
```

Here's what I want to do the same in react code (i.e., in the main component class)

```
class LoginForm extends  React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    //following method is to be called on onClick
    showAPopupAndAddContentAjax() {
      //code
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

So is there any way to call any react listener method? Or is there any different approach to achieve this?

PS: I just can't remove datatable code for now as it's already written and can't be replaced right now. Just need the listeners like **onClick**

Comment: Could you add some of your code to the question?

Comment: What you want to do with onClick like listener?

Comment: I need to show a popup with some data from ajax @BhojendraRauniyar The popup component is already rendered using react.

Comment: @CameronDowner just added.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can't do that. Because React works on virtual-dom concept and you want to interact with the core dom.

A tricky way to do that is to add class and trigger the popup open:

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-button", function(){
   $('#your_instance_of_component').addClass('open-popup');
});

// in your react app
const openPopup = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(LoginForm)
                  .getElementsByClassName('open-popup')//[0]

// implement the logic
if(openPopup.length) {
 // do the stuff
}
```

Hope, this helps!

---

**Update**

I just got another idea which will work fine:

In the jQuery listener, add the query parameter. And in the react app, you may call the dom listener on route change. You must give effort for this with some research. Hope, this helps now!

Comment: Okay. But how will my react component now the class has been added? The component is rendered on the page load only. So when will these lines ( `findDomNode` ) get executed?

Comment: You can use componentDidMount lifecycle. Ah, sorry, it would be available in render perhaps because jquery method is called after dom is ready. I'm not fully sure, but you may try on your own.

Comment: I guess you didn't get it. There was a typing mistake (*now the class* => *know the class*) in my above comment. Basically, I want to to this think after the page has been loaded and react component has been rendered. Say, after 15 minutes, I need to click the *non react* button. NOW, how will React know it has to execute these lines `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(LoginForm).getElementsByClassName('open-popup')` There must be something like listner / event by which React knows button is clicked. I just wan to know that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am saying to try in lifecycle or render. I think you didn't import ReactDom ?

Comment: You want to say render does rendering again when button is clicked? Secondly, lifecycle like `componentDidUpdate` ? (Have imported ReactDOM to render :))

Comment: No. It doesn't render. I mean to say your jquery method will be called after dom is ready and thus try inside render hook. You may try in component did mount hook but I am not sure if any of lifecycle hook can be used. The last option is to use render as per my understanding.

Comment: It's because the dom is rendered at that time when you click on the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178988/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-bhojendra-rauniyar).

Answer (score 1):

Setup an event listener which React listens for and update the state based on that.
This code snippet should give you the general idea.

```
$(document).on("click", ".my-button", function() {
  //show a popup and add content in it using ajax
  $(document).trigger( "show-my-react-popup" );
});

class Popup extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };

  showAPopupAndAddContentAjax = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  closePopup = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // jQuery code, should be refactored and removed in the future
    $(document).on("show-my-react-popup", () => {
      this.showAPopupAndAddContentAjax();
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // jQuery code, should be refactored and removed in the future
    $(document).off("show-my-react-popup");
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.open) return null;

    return (
      <div className="popup">
        <p>popup</p>
        <button onClick={this.closePopup}>close</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onmousedown onmouseup

[Source - HTML DOM Events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

There is alternative ways aswell, if using jQuery:

```
$('#SomeButton').click(function() { 
   functionTOevent();
});
```

*Use same idea as this, to get something in react.

Comment: Also, suggest to import React method in that file.

Comment: @VikasKumar depends, do you want to use jquery? if so, add it do you .js file, if you are using js. Or add this towards your element. onmouseup="YourStuff();"

Comment: You didn't get the question. Meanwhile I've edited the details. Please check you'll understand.

Comment: You can do multiple click events in different locations for same button. Updated fiddle, check it: https://jsfiddle.net/nm5usqb7/7/

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to use frameworks that use virtual DOM (React) with frameworks that use physical DOM (jQuery).

However, we can render React in only part of the application which avoids a lot of the risk between using both physical / virtual DOM.

I think something like this may work for your use case.

HTML

```
<button class="my-button">Render Component</button>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // load data with ajax
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is a react component</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function renderReact() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

$(document).on('click', '.my-button', function() {
  renderReact();
});
```

[You can see it working in this codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXqYmW)